# Trying to install Python's html5lib I get "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1

Tags: python, pip

In order to install Python's ´html5lib´ I have installed the latest version of setuptools:

```
sudo pip install setuptools --upgrade
```

and it got installed:

```
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:318: SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI (Subject Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform. This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate, which can cause validation failures. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#snimissingwarning.
SNIMissingWarning
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:122: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
InsecurePlatformWarning
Collecting setuptools
Downloading setuptools-25.1.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (442kB)
100% |████████████████████████████████| 450kB 658kB/s
Installing collected packages: setuptools
Found existing installation: setuptools 0.6c12dev-r85381
  Uninstalling setuptools-0.6c12dev-r85381:
  Successfully uninstalled setuptools-0.6c12dev-r85381
Successfully installed setuptools-25.1.6
```

But when I tried to install ´html5lib´:

```
wanzos-Mac-mini:python wanzo$ pip install html5lib
Collecting html5lib
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:318: SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI (Subject Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform. This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate, which can cause validation failures. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#snimissingwarning.
SNIMissingWarning
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:122: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
InsecurePlatformWarning
Using cached html5lib-0.999999999.tar.gz
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
html5lib requires setuptools version 18.5 or above; please upgrade before installing (you have 0.6c12)

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/vg/h8_286qs7cq4rcr2jfgdqb2h0000gn/T/pip-build-4h6oAR/html5lib/
```

It returned with **"python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1"**
The Python version is 2.7.1 and 19.01.2012 Build for Mac OS X.

Using this configuration, I had no problem installing ´lxml´and the it worked fine with all the scripts I tried. The only problem is when I try to install the ´html5lib´

To install it, I tried "easy_install" but I got this:

```
wanzos-Mac-mini:python wanzo$ sudo -H pip install easy_install
Collecting easy_install
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:318: SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI (Subject Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform. This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate, which can cause validation failures. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#snimissingwarning.
  SNIMissingWarning
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:122: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
InsecurePlatformWarning
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement easy_install (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for easy_install
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:122: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
InsecurePlatformWarning
```

I'm unable to install ´html5lib´ Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Where does your installation of `setuptools` come from? Try `easy_install --dry-run -U setuptools`; if it finds a newer version, try removing `--dry-run` and adding `sudo` if needed.

Comment: Why are you trying to install this globally instead of using a virtual environment?

Comment: installing it with 'upgrade' solved the problem:

# pip install html5lib --upgrade
  Collecting html5lib
  Downloading html5lib-0.999999999.tar.gz (245kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 245kB 702kB/s
Collecting six (from html5lib)
  Downloading six-1.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting webencodings (from html5lib)
  Downloading webencodings-0.5.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: six, webencodings, html5lib
  Found existing installation: six 1.8.0
    Uninstalling six-1.8.0:
Installed html5lib-0.999999999 six-1.10.0 webencodings-0.5

Comment: Hello 9000, your first suggestion (adding '--upgrade' for pip) solved the problem.  
The answer to your 2nd comment

Searching for setuptools
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/setuptools/
Best match: setuptools 25.1.6
Processing setuptools-25.1.6-py2.7.egg
setuptools 25.1.6 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
Installing easy_install script to /usr/local/bin
Installing easy_install-2.7 script to /usr/local/bin

Using /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/setuptools-25.1.6-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for setuptools
Finished processing dependencies for setuptools

Comment: Hello Two-Bit Alchemist, using a virtual environment crossed my mind but after I spent so much time tryin to install it the usual way, I decided to keep on that way. But the basic real reason was ´lxml´s being installed but html5lib's not being installed just didn't make any sense. And adding the ´--upgrade´ option to the pip install command solved that.